# How do I replace a whole string using replaceAll() method with a null value?

Tags: java, string, replaceall

I want to replace a certain string inside this sample file as a null value (empty string). I used "\" to escape whatever which will make my code work. I just want to replace " TERMINAL: "UNKNOWN" " which is found in this sample file

Sample File:

```
SESSIONID: "19670" ENTRYID: "1" STATEMENT: "1" USERID: "%USERNAME%" USERHOST: "%SRCHOSTNAME%" ACTION: "100" RETURNCODE: "0"
SESSIONID: "19670" ENTRYID: "435" STATEMENT: "20" USERID: "%USERNAME%" USERHOST: "%SRCHOSTNAME%" TERMINAL: "UNKNOWN" ACTION: "3" RETURNCODE: "0" 
SESSIONID: "19670" ENTRYID: "1" STATEMENT: "1" USERID: "%USERNAME%" USERHOST: "%SRCHOSTNAME%" ACTION: "101" RETURNCODE: "0
```

Expected Output:

```
SESSIONID: "19670" ENTRYID: "1" STATEMENT: "1" USERID: "%USERNAME%" USERHOST: "%SRCHOSTNAME%" ACTION: "100" RETURNCODE: "0"
SESSIONID: "19670" ENTRYID: "435" STATEMENT: "20" USERID: "%USERNAME%" USERHOST: "%SRCHOSTNAME%" ACTION: "3" RETURNCODE: "0" 
SESSIONID: "19670" ENTRYID: "1" STATEMENT: "1" USERID: "%USERNAME%" USERHOST: "%SRCHOSTNAME%" ACTION: "101" RETURNCODE: "0
```

My Code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("oracle.log"));
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    while (scan.hasNext()) {
        list.add(scan.next());
    }
    scan.close();

    try {
        //initiates a new File type file
        File file = new File("oracle.log");
        //initiates a new buffereed reader "reader"
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        //initialize 2 strings for comparison
        String line = "", oldtext = "";
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            oldtext += line + "\r\n";
        }
        reader.close();

        oldtext = oldtext.replaceAll("%TERMINAL: \"UNKNOWN\"", "");
        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("new_oracle.log");

        // the entire file is contained within the String 'oldtext'
        writer.write(oldtext);
        writer.close();
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Output:
The same sample file without any changes

Comment: The `%` character in your regular expression matches the literal '%' symbol. I'm not sure what you're trying to do there, but try removing it

Answer (score 1):

(based on my comment)
The `%` character in your regular expression matches the literal '%' symbol. I'm not sure what you're trying to do there, but try removing it.

I know in some cases `%` is used to match anything, in which case you can use `.*` in regular expressions, however this would remove everything in the line up until the end of the match.

`TERMINAL: \"UNKNOWN\"`

I tested it on regex101 and it works fine (quotes do not need to be escaped for this tool, but they do for java) https://regex101.com/r/eB2yW9/1

Answer (score 1):

You have an  unnecessary symbol in regexp. Just change your

```
oldtext = oldtext.replaceAll("%TERMINAL: \"UNKNOWN\"", "");
```

to

```
oldtext = oldtext.replaceAll("\\s*TERMINAL: \"UNKNOWN\"","");
```

With additional \s*, to delete all whitespaces before TERMINAL: "UNKNOWN"